# Checkbox text is not vertically aligned to the centre of the checkbox

Tags: android-studio, android-checkbox

I have `5 checkboxes` and each checkbox's' `text` is `misaligned vertically` from the center of the checkbox. I have tried adding a padding or a marging to the chckbox which has not helped, cause to my knowledge you can't add a padding specifically to the text. Heres an image that might explain my problem a little better!

[image: Checkbox text is misaligned on the first checkbox. The result I want is the 4th checkbox.]

Checkbox text is misaligned on the first checkbox. The result I want is the 4th checkbox.

**EDIT**

I create the checkboxes programmatically from an array:

```
    LinearLayout typeLinLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.typeLinLay);

    TableRow.LayoutParams checkParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    checkParams.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);

    for (int k = 0; k < config.checkBoxTypeFindViewById.length; k++)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        typeLinLayout.addView(checkBox, checkParams);

        checkBox.setId(config.checkBoxTypeFindViewById[k]);
        checkBox.setText(config.checkBoxTextType[k]);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(onCheckboxClickedType);
        checkBox.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        checkBox.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
        checkBox.setTextSize(16);
        checkBox.setAllCaps(true);
    }
```

Heres the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/mainTextBGColor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typesText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/optionsHeaders"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
            android:textColor="@color/mainBGColor"
            android:text="@string/optionsType"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/typeLinLay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/mainBGColor">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you please put your xml code here.

Comment: Please look at my edit.